# How to add a variable as a COUNTIF condition in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

What I'm trying to do is to add a variable as part of the condition of the function countif but it's not working.
Should I use Function countif or Formula countif?

Option Explicit

Sub tes()

```
 Dim ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet
 Dim i As Long
 Dim rngSearch As Range, rngFound As Range
 Dim arr As Variant
 Dim strValueC As String, strValueF As String

 With ThisWorkbook
    Set ws3 = .Worksheets("3 unprotected")
    Set ws4 = .Worksheets("DATA")
 End With

 With ws3
    arr = Range("A6:A33")
    Range("B6:C33").Clear
 End With

 Set rngSearch = ws4.Range("B1:B5049")

 For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

    Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:=arr(i, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then

        With ws4
            strValueC = .Range("C" & rngFound.Row).Value
            strValueF = .Range("F" & rngFound.Row).Value
        End With

        With ws3
            .Range("B" & i + 5).Value = strValueC
            .Range("C" & i + 5).Value = strValueF
            .Range("D" & i + 5).Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("DATA!B:B", "A" & i + 5))    'Error here, compile error. Argument not optial

        End With

    End If

 Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do... what should the result be?

Comment: The value of the series of cells in column D should be the counted elements in sheet(DATA) column A for the criteria(the value of the cell A) . For example in cell if the value of cell A6 is "soni " the cell D6 should take the value of counted cells that have the value "soni"

Comment: `.Range("D" & i + 5).Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(....)` and I'll leave you to finish the rest.

Comment: I've tried that as well but when it go to the .CountIf()   i put the range okay but as per the criteria of the CountIf I don't know how to put the value of cell A & i

Comment: `.Range("A" & i + 5).Value`?

Comment: it says compile error
argument not optimal

Comment: I've edited the question and pasted the full code. So you get an idea of what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("DATA").Range("B:B"), .Range("A" & i + 5).Value)`

Comment: @BigBen I salute you with awesomeness. It worked perfectly.